# Auto login for specific URL liferay

Tags: filter, liferay-7, autologin

I am trying to auto login for specific url like webdav url for document.
We want to modify documents uploaded to document library.
We are passing webdav url to ms office to open document. It is our intranet project and we are using ntlm.
I am unable to pass credentials from ms office to our liferay server.
When we click webdav url from our browser where I logged in already then it redirect to office and when office tries to open that document from liferay server then it is asking credentials, as I am already logged in then it should not ask credentials at the time of opening documents using ms office.
I am thinking if we do autologin for webdav url like url="/webdav/*" and able to do autologin then my issue would resolve.
Please help me on this. 
I am using liferay 7.2 CE.
Windows

Answer (score 0):

This is a long-standing issue that is not quite related to Liferay. The fact is that when you authenticate in Liferay from the browser it stores a session cookie inside that browser. When you open the webdav url, it's actually ms office that contacts the server and then it doesn't know about your browser cookies. So it does ask authentication on its own.

Now you are using NTLM which is Microsoft own SSO protocol, would it be nice that it does authenticate you on a Microsoft product. It's been a very long time since I had this exact same issue (2014, Liferay 6.1) but I believe NTLM info is only sent in network trusted sites and by default any site is not. You have to make change to your domain controller to allow them.

Next in that time, I think the Liferay NTLM filter was not called on a webdav path, we did have to create a hook to apply it. I don't know if it has been changed since then.

**Additional info asked in the comments**:

filter hook mapping documentation: 
https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-1/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/servlet-filters#step-2-map-urls-to-your-servlet-filter

The ootb ntlm filter is here: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/7.2.x/modules/apps/portal-security-sso-ntlm/portal-security-sso-ntlm-impl/src/main/java/com/liferay/portal/security/sso/ntlm/internal/servlet/filter/NtlmFilter.java

Comment: would u like to describe in details please which hook have u created, bcz I created so many classes hooks etc but nothing working. For webdav url unable to hit autologin. If I can hit autologin hook using webdav then it could solves my problem but it is not happening.

Comment: It was only a filter hook that registered the ootb ntlm filter on the /webdav/* path, but the way this is done now is really different with osgi

Comment: Any way to avoid credentials or able to do autologin using hook or ext please help me on this.

Comment: Yes, it’s possible, yes it might be hard to make it work, no I can’t do it for you in a SO answer. But I did add a reference to the hook documentation, you have to adapt it to filter on the webdav url and a reference to the existing ntlm filter that is already working for you to login the portal. Sorry if I can't be more specific, I would have to take a few days to set up a similar environment.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.
One thing I want to ask that how my custom filter for webdav will reference to any other filter. One more thing first it is hitting some security filter then WebDavServlet class or/and my custom filter of url /webdav/*